# Deploy web service as jar or war?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jar, jax-ws

I'm making a soap web service using JAX-WS.

Should this be deployed as war or jar.

Can it be deployed as a war?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would deploy it as a .war and could deploy it on a number of different servers (Tomcat would be one of the simplest HTTP servlet containers).

I suggest you read the following tutorial on deploying a web-service using JAX-WS on Tomcat.

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

Answer (score 1):

Soap web service is deployed as .war because it is a web application. What application server do you use? For example, in Glassfish simply you can put it in domain1/autodeploy directory.

Comment: I'm using glassfish. I have been able to deploy it as a jar by going to Applications and the deploying the Jar file. I'm not sure if jar or war is the best way to be deployed

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Glassfish then just build your application as .war (here there is no possibility to choose between two types) and deploy it either using Admin console or copy in autodeploy or use 'Deploy' button in your IDE.

How did you do this using Jar??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to deploy it as a war in order to get your server to properly process it.

What server are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using glassfish. I have been able o deploy it as a Jar. I'm still wondering which file type is better. Cheers.